# How to create dynamic form/filter items in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue js for my project and I'm very new to this language. I want to create a dynamic item selector in Vue js. I don't know about this where to start how to start. What I want is I have an input text field where the user enters the item name then a dropdown is shown below the input and the user can select the item. Once the item is selected it will be added to another div as shown in the attached image. User can add as many items as he wants already selected item won't be displayed in the dropdown. Once the items are selected that item will be used within the form to interact with a database to fetch the details or to filter the data. Attached is the image to make you understand what exactly I want.

[image]

I also want to what we call this feature in programming language.

Comment: What did you tried so far ? SO is more about solving the problems instead of providing a solution from the scratch.

Comment: Actually, I search the web for a solution but didn't find anything. Can you please just tell me what we call this feature so I will search the internet? Thank you

Comment: Please have a look into this `Vuetify` library https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is called chips. You may call custom dropdown chips. You can achieve the result with javascript, jquery, css. But in the case of Vue js, I would recommend it to you vuetify. Which is designed for Vue js to make the components better with less code.

Example :

```
    <template>
      <v-card
        class="mx-auto"
        max-width="500"
      >
        <v-col
          v-if="!allSelected"
          cols="12"
        >
          <v-text-field
            ref="search"
            v-model="search"
            class="search"
            hide-details
            label="Search"
            single-line
          />
        </v-col>
            
        <v-list class="list">
          <template v-for="item in categories">
            <v-list-item
              v-if="!selected.includes(item)"
              :key="item.text"
              :disabled="loading"
              @click="selected.push(item)"
            >
              <template #prepend>
                <v-icon
                  :disabled="loading"
                  :icon="item.icon"
                  :color="item.color"
                />
              </template>
    
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text" />
            </v-list-item>
          </template>
        </v-list>
    
        <v-container>
          <v-row
            align="center"
            justify="start"
          >
            <v-col
              v-for="(selection, i) in selections"
              :key="selection.text"
              cols="auto"
              class="py-1 pe-0"
            >
              <v-chip
                :disabled="loading"
                closable
                :color="selection.color"
                @click:close="selected.splice(i, 1)"
              >
                <v-icon
                  :icon="selection.icon"
                  start
                />
    
                {{ selection.text }}
              </v-chip>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
    
        <v-divider v-if="!allSelected" />
    
       
    
        <v-divider />
    
        <v-spacer />
    
        <v-btn
          :disabled="!selected.length"
          :loading="loading"
          color="purple"
          variant="text"
          @click="next"
        >
          Next
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </template>
```

Script :

```
    <script>
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        items: [
          {
            text: 'Nature',
            icon: 'mdi-nature',
            color: 'red',
          },
          {
            text: 'Nightlife',
            icon: 'mdi-glass-wine',
            color: 'yellow',
          },
          {
            text: 'November',
            icon: 'mdi-calendar-range',
            color: 'green',
          },
          {
            text: 'Portland',
            icon: 'mdi-map-marker',
            color: 'purple',
          },
          {
            text: 'Biking',
            icon: 'mdi-bike',
            color: 'orange',
          },
        ],
        loading: false,
        search: '',
        selected: [],
      }),
    
      computed: {
        allSelected () {
          return this.selected.length === this.items.length
        },
        categories () {
          const search = this.search.toLowerCase()
    
          if (!search) return this.items
    
          return this.items.filter(item => {
            const text = item.text.toLowerCase()
    
            return text.indexOf(search) > -1
          })
        },
        selections () {
          const selections = []
    
          for (const selection of this.selected) {
            selections.push(selection)
          }
    
          return selections
        },
      },
    
      watch: {
        selected () {
          this.search = ''
        },
      },
    
      methods: {
        next () {
          this.loading = true
    
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.search = ''
            this.selected = []
            this.loading = false
          }, 2000)
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Note: This example is taken from [Vuetify's](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/) official site. Also to get the result you first need to install Vuetify in your project.